# When does the short exact sequence of Module and submodule not split?

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, modules, homological-algebra, exact-sequence

Consider a commutative Ring $R$ and a module $M$ over $R$. Now let $N \subset M$ be a submodule. Then we have a canonical short exact sequence:
$$0 \rightarrow N \xrightarrow{i} M \xrightarrow{p}M/N \rightarrow 0$$

The $i$ is the inclusion and $p$ is the projection onto the quotient module. Up until now, I was under the impression that this sequence always splits by the splitting Lemma. The way I thought about it was, that the map
$$ r: M/N \rightarrow M\; ; \; m+N \mapsto m$$
defines a right-inverse to $p$, i.e. $p \circ r = id_{M/N}$. Since there are multiple $m$, mapping to the same element in $M/N$, I would choose a member of each class, sucht that the map becomes a homomorphism.

But I recently read that it only splits, if $N$ is a direct summand of $M$, which means that there is another submodule $N'$ such that $N \oplus N' = M$. But the existence of $N'$ somehow makes the splitting "obsolete", since this is exactly the definition of a split sequence. In other words, this is an if and only if statement. So $N$ is a direct summand iff the above SES splits. But this doesn't give me any more information on when this sequence splits... So my questions are the following:

1. Am I allowed to define $r$ in this way, and if yes, why is the map $r$ not a right-inverse to $p$?
2. Are there ways to check, if $N$ is a direct summand, without trying to split the above SES?
3. Can someone provide a counterexample of $N$ and $M$ such that the sequence does indeed not split?

Edit: I guess I have to clarify my question:
In the left map, I really want the canonical inclusion of $N$ into $M$ as a submodule. For example, I won't allow the sequence $0 \rightarrow \mathbb{Z} \xrightarrow{\cdot 2} \mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}_2 \rightarrow 0$. In this case, the left map would be $id$ and the right one $0$.

Comment: $r$ is not well-defined. *Many* $m$'s may be corresponding to the same $m+N$. You need to find a consistent way to pick exactly one of them.

Comment: For (3): Note $\mathbb Z$-modules are Abelian groups, look at $0\to \mathbb Z\to \mathbb Z\to \mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z\to 0$ where the first arrow is "multiply by 2" and the second is "take remainder $\pmod 2$".

Comment: Yes of course. But can't I just choose $m$ in its equivalence class, such that it becomes a homomorphism? Also, for your 2nd comment. This isn't the maps I am looking for. The first non-zero map should be the canonical inclusion of the submodule. In this case its the identity, which makes the 2nd map the 0-map.

Comment: I meant first map $\mathbb Z\to \mathbb Z$, $n\to 2n$, and the second map $\mathbb Z\to \mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$, $n\to n+2\mathbb Z$. Now, what would you map $1+2\mathbb Z\in\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$ *to*, in $\mathbb Z$ so that it is a homomorphism, when there are no elements in $\mathbb Z$ of order $2$?

Comment: Obviously $\mathbb Z\to \mathbb Z$, $n\to 2n$ is an injective homomorphism. If you prefer, call the first $\mathbb Z$ "$2\mathbb Z$" if you wish.

Comment: Why can't I just map $0 + 2\mathbb{Z}$ to $0 \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $1 + 2\mathbb{Z}$ to $1 \in \mathbb{Z}$? Also, The first map fould be $2 \mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z},$ $2n \mapsto 2n$...

Comment: @TimotheusHauptinius There is no such thing as a 'canonical inclusion'. In your terminology, this is nothing but the 'canonical inclusion' of the submodule $2\mathbb{Z}\subset\mathbb{Z}$

Comment: @TimotheusHauptinius Because this map is not a homomorphism. What does your map take $(1+2\mathbb{Z})+(1+2\mathbb{Z})$ to?

Comment: You can't because that won't be a homomorphism. Because $(1+2\mathbb Z)+(1+2\mathbb Z)=(0+2\mathbb Z)$ your map $r$ would have to satisfy $r(1+2\mathbb Z)+r(1+2\mathbb Z)=r(0+2\mathbb Z)$ i.e. $1+1=0$ i.e. $2=0$ in $\mathbb Z$.

Comment: Ahhhh okok. I get it now. I guess I didn't think this one through all the way. Thanks

Comment: In fact, there is only *one* single homomorphism from $\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$ to $\mathbb Z$ - *zero* homomorphism. (Everything maps to zero.) However, with that you cannot have $p\circ r=id$.

Comment: Yeah obviously. Somehow I always stumble on elementary things...bad habit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Your map is $r$ not well-defined. If $n\in N$, then $m+n+N=m+N$ in $M/N$, yet your 'map' $r$ maps these elements into $m+n$ and $m$ respectively.
2. Even if $N$ is a direct summand your sequence may not be split. There exist non-split sequences of the form
   $$0\to N\to N\oplus M\to M\to 0,$$
   because the left and right maps do not have to be the inclusion and the projection respectively.
3. Let $R=\mathbb{Z}.$ Then the sequence
   $$0\to\mathbb{Z}\xrightarrow{\cdot 2}\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}\to 0$$is not split.

Answer (score 3):

1. Why is your $r$ well-defined? To make it easier for you, think about an explicit example: Is $$\mathbb{Z}/42 \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}, \ n + 42 \mathbb{Z} \mapsto n$$ well-defined? (What are all maps $\mathbb{Z}/42 \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}$?)
2. Depending on the situation, there are many. For example, you can check whether the sequence is left-split. If you know that $N$ is an injective module or that $M/N$ is projective, then you also immediately know that the sequence splits. All of this is subsumed by the computation of $\operatorname{Ext}^1$-groups. Note however that being a direct summand is not the same thing as splitting, but you're probably interested in the splitting question for now.
3. Which examples have you looked at? There are plentiful of such examples. Look back at the example I suggest in 1 and play with it.